# Blank space between cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with several cells. If I do the swipe to delete (to remove a cell) it goes away but then I end up with blank space between my cells. It does not happen all the time. My cells are dequeued just fine. In the pic the green is my UITableView background and magenta is the UITableViewCell's content view. Where the space should be is where another cell should be; its just not drawing it. Using Xcode 9.2.

Any ideas as to why my cell isn't drawing?

My source for this VC is here:
https://github.com/bcgov/secure-image-ios/blob/master/SecureImage/UI/Albums/AlbumsViewController.swift

[image]

Comment: show us the code how you remove the cell

Comment: are `albums` automatically updated after `if DataServices.remove(album: album) {` ? I did not work with realm before..

Comment: does removing album from `albums` help?

Comment: Nope. I tried converting albums from `Results<Album>?` to `[Album]` and as @MilanNosáľ mentions below removing it. Same result. Does not always how up right away either. Some times I need to scroll up and down a few times before the bug presents itself.

Comment: If I add `tableView.reloadData()` just below my `tableView.endUpdates()` it fixes the problem but looks glitchy because of the reload.

Comment: try to use `tableView.setNeedsDisplay()` instead of `reloadData`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == .delete {
       print("Deleted")
       self.catNames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
       self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a source link to my original post. Pretty much what I do. Delete from Realm the remove the table row. Counts all look good (before and after) but I’ll double check.